# Sparse files are huge with io.Copy()

Tags: file, go, io, copy, sparse-file

I want to copy files from one place to another and the problem is I deal with a lot of sparse files.

Is there any (easy) way of copying sparse files without becoming huge at the destination?

My basic code:

```
out, err := os.Create(bricks[0] + "/" + fileName)
in, err := os.Open(event.Name)
io.Copy(out, in)
```

Comment: No, at least not an easy one. Spares files are something which depends on the filesystem used and ad hoc you have no idea whether your sink supports sparse files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Some background theory

Note that `io.Copy()` pipes raw bytes – which is sort of understandable once you consider that it pipes data from an `io.Reader` to an `io.Writer` which provide `Read([]byte)` and `Write([]byte)`, correspondingly.
As such, `io.Copy()` is able to deal with absolutely any source providing
bytes and absolutely any sink consuming them.

On the other hand, the location of the holes in a file is a "side-channel" information which "classic" syscalls such as `read(2)` hide from their users.
`io.Copy()` is not able to convey such side-channel information in any way.

IOW, initially, file sparseness was an idea to just have efficient storage of the data behind the user's back.

So, no, there's no way `io.Copy()` could deal with sparse files in itself.

#### What to do about it

You'd need to go one level deeper and implement all this using the `syscall` package and some manual tinkering.

To work with holes, you should use the `SEEK_HOLE` and `SEEK_DATA` special values for the `lseek(2)` syscall which are, while formally non-standard, are supported by [all](https://manpages.debian.org/jump?q=lseek.2) [major](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lseek&sektion=2) [platforms](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29032/lseek-2.html).

Unfortunately, the support for those "whence" positions is not present
neither in the stock `syscall` package (as of Go 1.8.1)
nor in the [`golang.org/x/sys`](https://github.com/golang/sys/) tree.

But fear not, there are two easy steps:

1. First, the stock `syscall.Seek()` is actually mapped to `lseek(2)`
   on the relevant platforms.
2. Next, you'd need to figure out the correct values for `SEEK_HOLE` and
   `SEEK_DATA` for the platforms you need to support.

   > *Note that they are **free to be different** between different platforms!*

   Say, on my Linux system I can do simple

   ```
   $ grep -E 'SEEK_(HOLE|DATA)' </usr/include/unistd.h 
   #  define SEEK_DATA     3       /* Seek to next data.  */
   #  define SEEK_HOLE     4       /* Seek to next hole.  */
   ```

   …to figure out the values for these symbols.

Now, say, you create a Linux-specific file in your package
containing something like

```
// +build linux

const (
    SEEK_DATA = 3
    SEEK_HOLE = 4
)
```

and then use these values with the `syscall.Seek()`.

The file descriptor to pass to `syscall.Seek()` and friends
can be obtained from an opened file using the `Fd()` method
of `os.File` values.

The pattern to use when reading is to detect regions containing data, and read the data from them – see [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/sparse.c?id=63f2e969ddc162da7ae49a955bba9c6a2a0e77dc#n287) for one example.

Note that this deals with reading sparse files; but if you'd want to actually *transfer* them as sparse – that is, with keeping this property of them, – the situation is more complicated: it appears to be even less portable, so some research and experimentation is due.

On Linux, it appears you could try to use [`fallocate(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/jump?q=fallocate.2) with
`FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE` to try to punch a hole at the
end of the file you're writing to; if that legitimately fails
(with `syscall.EOPNOTSUPP`), you just shovel as many zeroed blocks to the destination file as covered by the hole you're reading – in the hope
the OS will do the right thing and will convert them to a hole by itself.

Note that some filesystems do not support holes at all – as a concept.
One example is the filesystems in the FAT family.
What I'm leading you to is that inability of creating a sparse file might
actually be a property of the target filesystem in your case.

You might find [Go issue #13548 "archive/tar: add support for writing tar containing sparse files"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13548) to be of interest.

---

One more note: you might also consider checking whether the destination directory to copy a source file resides in the same filesystem as the source file, and if this holds true, use the `syscall.Rename()` (on POSIX systems)
or `os.Rename()` to just move the file across different directories w/o
actually copying its data.

Comment: I didn't expect such a comprehensive answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to resort to syscalls.

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create("/tmp/sparse.dat")
    f.Write([]byte("start"))
    f.Seek(1024*1024*10, 0)
    f.Write([]byte("end"))
}
```

Then you'll see:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/sparse.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soren soren 10485763 Jun 25 14:29 /tmp/sparse.dat
$ du /tmp/sparse.dat
8   /tmp/sparse.dat
```

It's true you can't use `io.Copy` as is.  Instead you need to implement an alternative to `io.Copy` which reads a chunk from the `src`, checks if it's all `'\0'`. If it is, just `dst.Seek(len(chunk), os.SEEK_CUR)` to skip past that part in `dst`. That particular implementation is left as an exercise to the reader :)